# Ubuntu is frozen on my computer

Tags: 16.04, freeze

I'm a new user of Ubuntu, I'm start using it 3 days ago, but something is not OK. Sometimes my pc is frozen, it not respond to any keyboard combination nor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I was waiting for 1 hour for something to happen, but nothing.

This not happen always, is really weird, because it happens the PC is not running hard software, in fact, it came to frozen in the same desktop (without any open software). My solution for avoid the frozen is press the button of reset since my computer case, but I want to use Ubuntu with any problem.

The installation is Totally new, I format completely to use Ubuntu like my new operative system, someone have any idea of what happens here?

My computer's specifications:

[image]

Comment: Before install Ubuntu, I had Windows 7 and it worked OK, this situation is very weird :(

Comment: It's probably a software issue then: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to [verify the integrity of the main memory modules](/q/591488/175814) in case it's a hardware issue after all.